# PHP if statements - logic

Tags: php, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

`some_function($input)` returns the integer `23`

`$other_int` has a value that is not equal to `23`

Code snippet 1

```
if ($int = some_function($input) && $int != $other_int) {...}
```

Code snippet 2

```
$int = some_function($input);
if ($int != $other_int) {...}
```

I coded snippet 1 thinking that the if statement would return true given the above conditions.  I was wrong.

The if statement in snippet 2 is true.

Why?

Comment: you can't put an assignment inside the if clause

Comment: @Dagon Yes you can. That's the whole point of this question. Why does this code yield an expected result when assignment is outside of the clause rather than inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `&&` has higher precedence than assignment, so you're performing the logical operation **before** you assign to the variable.

Instead of `&&` you can use `and`. `and` and `or` have lower precedence than assignment, and are intended precisely for situations like this.

```
if ($int = some_function($input) and $int != $other_int)
```

Answer (score 4):

So, assignments in an if clause like that is a bad practice for a reason.  That said, you're not assigning what you think you are. This is what you're actually doing:

```
$int = (some_function($input) && $int != $other_int);
```

which evaluates to true.  To get the result you want, change the code to

```
if (($int = some_function($input)) && ($int != $other_int)) {...}
```

But really, don't assign variables in an if() statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` and the `!=` have higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

So inside the conditional:

```
if ($int = some_function($input) && $int != $other_int) {...}
```

It executes the `!=` then the `&&`, but `$int` hasn't been initialized yet (assuming you haven't initialized it outside that conditional) so the right side `!=` always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value like that inside the `if` statement AND compare that value in the same statement

https://3v4l.org/FlE6u

```
<?php

function somefunc() {
    return 23;
}

if($int = somefunc() && $int == 23) {
    echo 'Equal';
} else {
    echo 'Not Equal';
}
echo "\n";
var_dump($int);
```

You'll note the error

> Notice: Undefined variable: int in /in/GHVKs on line 7

And at the end `$int` is `false`. Assign it outside your `if`

Comment: Although I don't personally like the approach, you __can__ assign and compare in the `if` statement, the OP is just missing the parenthesis for order of operations, no?. [https://3v4l.org/IPDQK](https://3v4l.org/IPDQK)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, a variable cannot be both initialized and used within the condition of an `if` statement. You may have found a bug/feature of php.

```
function some_function()
{
    return 23;
}

$intA = 0;
if ($intA = some_function()
    && $intA != $other_int
) {
    echo 'hello world!'; // works fine
}

if ($intB = some_function()
    && $intB != $other_int
) {
    echo 'hello world!'; // PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: intB
}
```